# TRPC: SetData (SetQueryData) takes way too long

Tags: react-query, trpc

So I have this simple bio component.

Whenever I mutate I want to optimistically update the state.

But it doesn't work and doesn't throw any errors either.

In fact, when just invalidating the queries without setting the state myself, it still takes forever or doesn't invalidate at all.

Here's the code

```js
"use client";
import { z } from "zod";
import { useAuthenticatedSession } from "~/components/AuthOnly/Client";
import { SubmitHandler, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { RiPencilLine } from "react-icons/ri";
import { TextArea } from "~/components/Inputs";
import { TextButton } from "~/components/Button";
import FormCard from "./FormCard";
import { api } from "~/utils/api";
import { BioSchema } from "~/server/api/validators/user";
import { MAX_BIO_LENGTH } from "~/constants";

const BioValidator = z.object({ bio: BioSchema });

export default function Bio() {
  type Form = z.infer<typeof BioValidator>;
  const {
    user: { id },
  } = useAuthenticatedSession();
  const { mutate } = api.user.setBio.useMutation({
    onMutate: async (data) => {
      await apiUtils.user.getBio.cancel({ id });
      const previousBio = apiUtils.user.getBio.getData({ id });
      apiUtils.user.getBio.setData({ id }, data.bio);
      return () => apiUtils.user.getBio.setData({ id }, previousBio);
    },
    onError: (_error, _variables, rollback) => {
      if (rollback) {
        rollback();
      }
    },
    onSettled: async () => {
      await apiUtils.user.getBio.invalidate({ id });
    },
  });
  const apiUtils = api.useContext();
  const {
    data: bio,
    error,
    isLoading,
  } = api.user.getBio.useQuery({
    id,
  });
  const { register, formState, handleSubmit, setError } = useForm<Form>({
    mode: "onChange",
  });
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<Form> = (data) => {
    const bio = data.bio;
    if (bio) {
      mutate({ bio });
    }
  };
  if (error) throw error;
  return (
    <FormCard icon={<RiPencilLine />} title="Add a short bio">
      <p className="text-sm mb-2">
        This goes in the &quot;About Me&quot; section of your Channel. Must be
        under 300 characters.
      </p>
      {isLoading ? (
        <p>loading...</p>
      ) : (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <TextArea
            id="bioTextarea"
            {...register("bio", {
              required: true,
              value: bio ?? "",
              maxLength: MAX_BIO_LENGTH,
              validate: (value) => {
                if (value === bio) {
                  return "You must change your bio to submit it.";
                }
              },
            })}
            defaultValue={bio ?? ""}
            placeholder="e.g., What games you play, what your on-stream personality is like, what makes you unique."
            spellCheck={false}
            maxLength={300}
            rows={4}
            className="mt-2"
          />
          <TextButton
            type="submit"
            disabled={!formState.isValid}
            variant="primary"
            className="transition block mt-4 ml-auto"
          >
            Submit
          </TextButton>
        </form>
      )}
    </FormCard>
  );
}
```

Additionally, here's the context (Next.js /app)

```js
function TRPCProvider({ children }: PropsWithChildren) {
  const [queryClient] = useState(() => new QueryClient({}));
  const trpcClient = useTRPCClient();
  return (
    <api.Provider client={trpcClient} queryClient={queryClient}>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>{children}</QueryClientProvider>
    </api.Provider>
  );
}
export function useTRPCClient() {
  return useState(() => {
    return api.createClient({
      transformer: superjson,
      links: [
        loggerLink({
          enabled: (opts) =>
            logTRPC &&
            (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ||
              (opts.direction === "down" && opts.result instanceof Error)),
        }),
        httpBatchLink({
          url: `${getBaseUrl()}/api/trpc`,
        }),
      ],
    });
  })[0];
}
```